# How to swich grid workspaces horizontally on Ubuntu18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I have successfully changed the vertical list workspaces to grid workspaces on Ubuntu18.04 by following command and application.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
gnome-tweaks
```

gnome-tweaks -> Extensions -> workspace grid

However, I cannot how to change the keyboard setting of switching the workspaces.
I can use super+ctrl+j or k as the default settings, but I cannnot move the workspace horizontally.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?
I think that one of possible solutions is assign new keyboardshortcut as command which switchs work spaces but I cannnot find this command.

(Please excuse my poor English.)

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and type the following for horizontal switching:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right "['<Shift><Ctrl><Alt>Right']"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left "['<Shift><Ctrl><Alt>Left']"
```

and for vertical switching:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "['<Shift><Ctrl><Alt>Up']"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "['<Shift><Ctrl><Alt>Down']"
```

Comment: This was close, except the key was "switch" and not "move". To make it like Windows, I had to do: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['<Ctrl><Super>Right']"` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Ctrl><Super>Left']"`

Comment: you need both, move and switch

Answer (score -2):

You can switch using the arrows, i.e. super+ctrl+up or super+ctrl+down.

Comment: But what about left and right? The horizontal grid seems to have been removed.